# Nextjs + Next-i18next: change of language always reloads page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next, next-i18next

I am trying to implement localization with next-i18next on the website(single page), everything works as it should be except when I change the language through the nextjs router, the page always reloads and returns to the top of the page (obviously I want only components to re-render with different language), And I cannot figure out why is that so ( maybe something with getStaticProps that I am missing ? ).

under are snippets from my code:

next-i18next.config

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en', 'cs'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
    },
};
```

App file --> I am also pulling some data from MongoDB with getStaticProps for my components

```
interface HomeProps {
    featuredProjectsData: ProjectProps[];
    projectCardsData: CardProps[];
    locale: any;
}

const Home: NextPage<HomeProps> = ({ projectCardsData, featuredProjectsData,locale }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
                <meta
                    name='description'
                    content='Welcome to my personal website, where you can find information about me, my work/projects and also contact details'
                />
            </Head>

            {useMediaQuery(darkTheme.breakpoints.up('md')) && <Socials />}
            <Header />
            <Container maxWidth='lg'>
                <main>
                    <HeroSection />
                    <About />
                    <Skills />
                    <FeaturedProjects projects={featuredProjectsData} />
                    <ProjectCards cards={projectCardsData} />
                    <Contact />
                </main>
                <Footer />
            </Container>
        </>
    );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db('personal-website'); // accessing db
    let featuredCollection = await db.collection('featured').find({}).toArray(); // accessing collection & getting all documents
    let projectsCollection = await db.collection('projects').find({}).toArray();
    featuredCollection = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(featuredCollection));
    projectsCollection = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projectsCollection));

    return {
        props: {
            featuredProjectsData: featuredCollection.map((featured) => ({
                title: featured.title,
                description: featured.desc,
                tech: featured.usedtech,
                image: featured.img,
                links: featured.links,
                id: featured._id.toString(),
            })),
            projectCardsData: projectsCollection.map((project) => ({
                title: project.title,
                description: project.desc,
                tags: project.tags,
                links: project.links,
                id: project._id,
            })),
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale as string, ['common'])),
        },
    };
};

export default Home;
```

Options ( here I am defining LI to toggle between langs )

```
const Options = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { theme, resolvedTheme, setTheme } = useTheme();
    const loaded = useLoaded();
    return (
        <StyledOptions>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => setTheme(resolvedTheme === 'light' ? 'dark':'light')}
                    >
                        {theme === 'dark' && loaded ? <MdLightMode /> : <MdDarkMode />}
                    </IconButton>
                </li>
                <li onClick={() => router.push('/', '/', { locale: 'cs' })}>
                    CZK
                </li>
                <li onClick={() => router.push('/', '/', { locale: 'en' })} >
                    ENG
                </li>
            </ul>
        </StyledOptions>
    );
};

export default Options;
```

HeroSection  - Here I am calling useTranslation hook and display string
const HeroSection = () => {
let { t } = useTranslation();
return (


{t('common:welcome_msg')}


);

common file from /public/locales/en

```
{ "welcome_msg": "Hello there, I am" }
```

Thank you for any advice or direction where to search

Comment: Are you sure the page is fully reloading and not just re-rendering? If the issue is the scroll to top behaviour, you can disable it by passing `scroll: false` in the options of the `router.push` call, e.g. `router.push('/', '/', { locale: 'cs', scroll: false })`.

Comment: I have this problem too, and seems it cannot be helped...